# I'm having trouble with excel linked with java script

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I'm making a website which hosts video tutorials. I have created a static version of it but that involves individually typing the urls of each video in the code. I'm looking for a way to access these urls from a excel sheet so that it becomes dynamic ie, if you add another url to the excel it automatically gets added to the site. Any ideas??

Comment: that makes no sense, it would be the other way around you can make a vba scripts that auto updates when you update your site

Comment: I was plannin on using jexcel to get the specific urls from the spreadsheet and storing in an array which can be uploaded onto the database. But now the prblem i'm facing is with the array size. Could you suggest what to do about that??